# ADD new node Replication in MongoDB

Tags: replication, mongodb, linux, data-synchronization

Here i found some trouble. and i don't known why!

Now I have one replication with 3 members (1 of primary, 2 of secondary),

And i want to add another one (secondary) to sync the data.

the data has 367G .

When finished sync the data ,the new secondary in the replication has been down itself, then i start this node, he delete the data and starting sync again.
I don't known why,

please help me.

1. mongodb version 3.3.10
2. the oplog in primary has 9G
3. the disk have more than 654G , 38%Use
4. when i send this command in mongo shell

   rs.add({host:'172.16.30.123:27017',priority:0,votes:0})

   rs.status()

```js
{
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "172.16.30.123:27017",
      "health": 1,
      "state": 5,
      "stateStr": "STARTUP2",
      "uptime": 10029,
      "optime": {
        "ts": Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t": NumberLong("-1")
      },
      "optimeDurable": {
        "ts": Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t": NumberLong("-1")
      },
      "optimeDate": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "optimeDurableDate": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2018-05-10T12:28:40.256Z"),
      "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2018-05-10T12:28:40.722Z"),
      "pingMs": NumberLong("0"),
      "syncingTo": "172.16.30.225:27017",
      "configVersion": 9
    },
```

now,you can see the node is syncingto 172.16.30.225

here is the node's log

```js
2018-05-10T17:01:14.247+0800 I REPL     [InitialSyncInserters-0] starting to run synchronous task on runner.
2018-05-10T17:01:14.373+0800 I REPL     [InitialSyncInserters-0] done running the synchronous task.
2018-05-10T17:01:14.458+0800 I REPL     [InitialSyncInserters-0] starting to run synchronous task on runner.
2018-05-10T17:01:14.575+0800 I REPL     [InitialSyncInserters-0] done running the synchronous task.
2018-05-10T17:01:14.575+0800 I REPL     [InitialSyncInserters-0] starting to run synchronous task on runner.
2018-05-10T17:01:14.989+0800 I REPL     [InitialSyncInserters-0] done running the synchronous task.
2018-05-10T17:01:14.989+0800 I REPL     [replication-82] data clone finished, status: OK
2018-05-10T17:01:14.991+0800 F EXECUTOR [replication-82] Exception escaped task in thread pool replication
2018-05-10T17:01:14.991+0800 F -        [replication-82] terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information
2018-05-10T17:01:15.008+0800 F -        [replication-82] DBException::toString(): 2 source in remote command request cannot be empty
Actual exception type: mongo::UserException

 0x55d8112ca811 0x55d8112ca0d5 0x55d811d102a6 0x55d811d102f1 0x55d811249418 0x55d811249dd0 0x55d81124a979 0x55d811d2b040 0x7f04a287ce25 0x7f04a25aa34d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"144B811","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"144B0D5"},{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"1E912A6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE"},{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"1E912F1"},{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"13CA418","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool10_doOneTaskEPSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"13CADD0","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool13_consumeTasksEv"},{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"13CB979","s":"_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool17_workerThreadBodyEPS0_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE"},{"b":"55D80FE7F000","o":"1EAC040","s":"execute_native_thread_routine"},{"b":"7F04A2875000","o":"7E25"},{"b":"7F04A24B2000","o":"F834D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.3.10", "gitVersion" : "4d826acb5648a78d0af0fefac5abe6fbbe7c854a", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64", "version" : "#1 SMP Thu Jan 25 20:13:58 UTC 2018", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "55D80FE7F000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "76E66D90C81BC61AF236A1AF6A6F753332397346" }, { "b" : "7FFE6A6DB000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "47E1DE363A68C3E5970550C87DAFA3CCF9713953" }, { "b" : "7F04A3816000", "path" : "/lib64/libssl.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "ED0AC7DEB91A242C194B3DEF27A215F41CE43116" }, { "b" : "7F04A33B5000", "path" : "/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BC0AE9CA0705BEC1F0C0375AAD839843BB219CB1" }, { "b" : "7F04A31AD000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6D322588B36D2617C03C0F3B93677E62FCFFDA81" }, { "b" : "7F04A2FA9000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E42EBFB272D37B726F457D6FE3C33D2B094BB69" }, { "b" : "7F04A2CA7000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "808BD35686C193F218A5AAAC6194C49214CFF379" }, { "b" : "7F04A2A91000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3E85E6D20D2CE9CDAD535084BEA56620BAAD687C" }, { "b" : "7F04A2875000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A48D21B2578A8381FBD8857802EAA660504248DC" }, { "b" : "7F04A24B2000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "95FF02A4BEBABC573C7827A66D447F7BABDDAA44" }, { "b" : "7F04A3A88000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "22FA66DA7D14C88BF36C69454A357E5F1DEFAE4E" }, { "b" : "7F04A2265000", "path" : "/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA322D74F55A0C4293085371A8D0E94B5962F5E7" }, { "b" : "7F04A1F7D000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B69E63024D408E400401EEA6815317BDA38FB7C2" }, { "b" : "7F04A1D79000", "path" : "/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A3832734347DCA522438308C9F08F45524C65C9B" }, { "b" : "7F04A1B46000", "path" : "/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A48639BF901DB554479BFAD114CB354CF63D7D6E" }, { "b" : "7F04A1930000", "path" : "/lib64/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EA8E45DC8E395CC5E26890470112D97A1F1E0B65" }, { "b" : "7F04A1722000", "path" : "/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6FDF5B013FD2739D304CFB9D723DCBC149EE03C9" }, { "b" : "7F04A151E000", "path" : "/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2E01D5AC08C1280D013AAB96B292AC58BC30A263" }, { "b" : "7F04A1304000", "path" : "/lib64/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FF4E72F4E574E143330FB3C66DB51613B0EC65EA" }, { "b" : "7F04A10DD000", "path" : "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A88379F56A51950A33198890D37F5F8AEE71F8B4" }, { "b" : "7F04A0E7B000", "path" : "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9CA3D11F018BEEB719CDB34BE800BF1641350D0A" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55d8112ca811]
 mongod(+0x144B0D5) [0x55d8112ca0d5]
 mongod(_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+0x6) [0x55d811d102a6]
 mongod(+0x1E912F1) [0x55d811d102f1]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool10_doOneTaskEPSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x3C8) [0x55d811249418]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool13_consumeTasksEv+0xC0) [0x55d811249dd0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool17_workerThreadBodyEPS0_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x149) [0x55d81124a979]
 mongod(execute_native_thread_routine+0x20) [0x55d811d2b040]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x7E25) [0x7f04a287ce25]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f04a25aa34d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Actual exception type: mongo::UserException

at last the mongo process has been shutdown,when i start it again,it's will delete the data and start sync again

here is the full output of rs.status()

```
 {
  "set": "rs0",
  "date": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:19.313Z"),
  "myState": 1,
  "term": NumberLong("3"),
  "heartbeatIntervalMillis": NumberLong("2000"),
  "optimes": {
    "lastCommittedOpTime": {
      "ts": Timestamp(1525999999, 6),
      "t": NumberLong("3")
    },
    "appliedOpTime": {
      "ts": Timestamp(1525999999, 6),
      "t": NumberLong("3")
    },
    "durableOpTime": {
      "ts": Timestamp(1525999999, 5),
      "t": NumberLong("3")
    }
  },
  "members": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "172.16.30.223:27017",
      "health": 1,
      "state": 1,
      "stateStr": "PRIMARY",
      "uptime": 20032944,
      "optime": {
        "ts": Timestamp(1525999999, 6),
        "t": NumberLong("3")
      },
      "optimeDate": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:19Z"),
      "electionTime": Timestamp(1505967067, 1),
      "electionDate": ISODate("2017-09-21T04:11:07Z"),
      "configVersion": 9,
      "self": true
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "172.16.30.224:27017",
      "health": 1,
      "state": 2,
      "stateStr": "SECONDARY",
      "uptime": 9748305,
      "optime": {
        "ts": Timestamp(1525999998, 23),
        "t": NumberLong("3")
      },
      "optimeDurable": {
        "ts": Timestamp(1525999998, 23),
        "t": NumberLong("3")
      },
      "optimeDate": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:18Z"),
      "optimeDurableDate": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:18Z"),
      "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:18.751Z"),
      "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:18.697Z"),
      "pingMs": NumberLong("0"),
      "syncingTo": "172.16.30.223:27017",
      "configVersion": 9
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "172.16.30.225:27017",
      "health": 1,
      "state": 2,
      "stateStr": "SECONDARY",
      "uptime": 20032938,
      "optime": {
        "ts": Timestamp(1525999998, 21),
        "t": NumberLong("3")
      },
      "optimeDurable": {
        "ts": Timestamp(1525999998, 21),
        "t": NumberLong("3")
      },
      "optimeDate": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:18Z"),
      "optimeDurableDate": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:18Z"),
      "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:18.751Z"),
      "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:19.029Z"),
      "pingMs": NumberLong("0"),
      "syncingTo": "172.16.30.223:27017",
      "configVersion": 9
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "172.16.30.123:27017",
      "health": 0,
      "state": 8,
      "stateStr": "(not reachable/healthy)",
      "uptime": 0,
      "optime": {
        "ts": Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t": NumberLong("-1")
      },
      "optimeDurable": {
        "ts": Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t": NumberLong("-1")
      },
      "optimeDate": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "optimeDurableDate": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:17.635Z"),
      "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2018-05-10T15:24:23.323Z"),
      "pingMs": NumberLong("0"),
      "lastHeartbeatMessage": "Connection refused",
      "configVersion": -1
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "name": "172.16.30.127:27017",
      "health": 0,
      "state": 8,
      "stateStr": "(not reachable/healthy)",
      "uptime": 0,
      "optime": {
        "ts": Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t": NumberLong("-1")
      },
      "optimeDurable": {
        "ts": Timestamp(0, 0),
        "t": NumberLong("-1")
      },
      "optimeDate": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "optimeDurableDate": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
      "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2018-05-11T00:53:17.454Z"),
      "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2018-05-10T09:01:26.996Z"),
      "pingMs": NumberLong("0"),
      "lastHeartbeatMessage": "Connection refused",
      "configVersion": -1
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
```

and rs.conf(), the status was two node finished sync , and two node's mongodb process was been done, the primary's status show the informations like this.Normaly the status should  STARTUP2 became SECONDARY.

```
    {
  "_id": "rs0",
  "version": 9,
  "protocolVersion": NumberLong("1"),
  "members": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "host": "172.16.30.223:27017",
      "arbiterOnly": false,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 1,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong("0"),
      "votes": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "host": "172.16.30.224:27017",
      "arbiterOnly": false,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 1,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong("0"),
      "votes": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "host": "172.16.30.225:27017",
      "arbiterOnly": false,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 1,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong("0"),
      "votes": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "host": "172.16.30.123:27017",
      "arbiterOnly": false,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 0,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong("0"),
      "votes": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "host": "172.16.30.127:27017",
      "arbiterOnly": false,
      "buildIndexes": true,
      "hidden": false,
      "priority": 0,
      "tags": {

      },
      "slaveDelay": NumberLong("0"),
      "votes": 0
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "chainingAllowed": true,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis": 2000,
    "heartbeatTimeoutSecs": 10,
    "electionTimeoutMillis": 10000,
    "getLastErrorModes": {

    },
    "getLastErrorDefaults": {
      "w": 1,
      "wtimeout": 0
    },
    "replicaSetId": ObjectId("5994eb51712e4cd82e549341")
  }
}
```

here is the  rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()

```
    localhost(mongod-3.3.10)[PRIMARY:rs0] admin> rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
source: 172.16.30.224:27017
    syncedTo: Fri May 11 2018 09:37:13 GMT+0800 (CST)
    1 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: 172.16.30.225:27017
    syncedTo: Fri May 11 2018 09:37:13 GMT+0800 (CST)
    1 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
source: 172.16.30.123:27017
    syncedTo: Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
    1526002634 secs (423889.62 hrs) behind the primary 
source: 172.16.30.127:27017
    syncedTo: Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
    1526002634 secs (423889.62 hrs) behind the primary 
localhost(mongod-3.3.10)[PRIMARY:rs0] admin>
```

the oplog information

```
localhost(mongod-3.3.10)[PRIMARY:rs0] local> show tables
me               →    0.000MB /    0.016MB
oplog.rs         → 9319.549MB / 3418.199MB
replset.election →    0.000MB /    0.035MB
startup_log      →    0.009MB /    0.035MB
system.replset   →    0.001MB /    0.035MB
localhost(mongod-3.3.10)[PRIMARY:rs0] local>
```

Comment: Why are you using MongoDB 3.3.10? It's not a stable version. The stable versions are marked with even numbers on the second set, e.g. 3.2.x, 3.4.x, or 3.6.x.

Comment: Please also post the full output of `rs.status()` and `rs.conf()`

Comment: the node 30.123 and the node 30.127 was add by myself,when sync finished , the processes of two mongodb will be done .

Comment: when i add one node by one time , it's also like that

Comment: I suspect your oplog is not long enough, so while the two nodes are doing initial sync, it fell off the oplog and cannot recover. Two questions: 1) What's the output of `rs.printReplicationInfo()` and 2) How long before the newly added nodes exhibit this error?

Comment: the newly added nodes begin sync data at 09:16 ,and finished at 17:01.You can see the logs in the page. And the oplog have 9G,i think it's enough for sync . the logs show "Actual exception type: mongo::UserException"  will it be User problem?

Comment: I don't think it's user issue. If you're certain you have enough oplog, the other thing to try is to upgrade to MongoDB 3.4.14 (currently latest in 3.4 series) to ensure that you're not hitting some old issue. Remember that the 3.3 series is a development unstable series, so there might be some issues with it. Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/ for upgrade procedures.

Comment: ok thanks,  by the way i did the same thing in mongdb 3.6 was successly and the data is only 1G

Comment: And i found that the old replication system version is centos7  , and newly added nodes system version is centos 6.5 , but mongodb version are the same v3.3.10 . will it be affected?

Comment: Although it should not have any issue with the same MongoDB version, different OS might have different "quirks" so it's a good idea to have all nodes in a replica set to have uniform MongoDB and OS versions, and also provisioned with the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As i am able to see that in your log files there is exception such as

```
2018-05-10T17:01:15.008+0800 F -        [replication-82] DBException::toString(): 2 source in remote command request cannot be empty
Actual exception type: mongo::UserException
```

As per `MongoDB` jira documentation [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23976?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24563) you could successfully create two databases that only differ by case, and insert data into both. But new clients would have trouble accessing either one – in addition to the crash you would experience on secondaries of a replica set.

> Cause Type : Bug
>
> Affects Version/s:
>   3.3.3
>
> Fix Version/s:
>   3.5.1